# Object reference not set for an instance of an object after updating visual studio 2013 to update 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, installation

After I Update the Visual Studio, when i create a MVC project, reference like Owin and other references didn't added to it,

but when i tried to run the visual studio in safemode this couldn't happen, only this time i encountered this problem, could it be bug? o what, my head aching to this.

i also tried to uninstall the installed **nuget package manager** and installed it again as a suggestion of other, also tried this ***devenv.exe /ResetSettings*** to reset the visual studio for hoping resolve this problem but problem still there. somebody help me solve this problem.

[image: Error]

here also some picture

[image: references missing]

**Problem Solved:**

> Missing references created from normal mode means some component didn't load successfully to its destination, it might be a bug from nuget, after i try and try to add all missing component to nuget by installing-package and try again to used **devenv.exe /ResetSettings** problem fixed.

Comment: Note to future readers: this is _not_ a duplicate of the canonical NullReferenceException question. The exception is not from the OP's code, but from Visual Studio.